# Anypoint studio (mulesoft)

Tags: postman, anypoint-studio

I am new to the mulesoft. I want to get a particular value or I'd from the set of details without using database.

So I used file connector and to post and get my values.
I used mule requestor to read the file as a middle work to convert CSV file to json. And now it is retrieving all the values as a JSON format. I couldn't able to get the particular id..

Can anyone please help to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you are getting the below data as json format

```
{
    "entries": [{
        "Profile Status": "3",
        "Remedy Login ID": "jorge.hawkins",
        "Person ID": "KKPPPLL123212457788"
    }]
}
```

Then please try the below syntax to fetch the particular ID from your json data

```
 #[json:entries[0]/'Person ID']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your payload from json to to java using transform message processor. This will help you to traverse to any node in your object. Traversing in a java object is much simpler then in any other object type.
If your want to retrieve the status of customer with name "GHI" in the payload below, you can transform the json to java using transform message processor and use the expression below "payload[2].customer_detail.customer_status" to retrieve the detail . eg. json`[{
    "customer_name": "ABC",
    "customer_id": "1_ABC",
    "customer_detail": {
        "customer_age": 30,
        "customer_status": "Active"
    }
},
{
    "customer_name": "DEF",
    "customer_id": "2_DEF",
    "customer_detail": {
        "customer_age": 31,
        "customer_status": "Inactive"
    }
},
{
    "customer_name": "GHI",
    "customer_id": "3_GHI",
    "customer_detail": {
        "customer_age": 32,
        "customer_status": "Active"
    }
},
]`